# Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '-1'

Tags: chef-infra

So I am not sure what is the '-1' exit about, other questions similar to this, could not resolve my problem :(. I am running the following resource:

```
execute 'Install AD' do
  command install_command
  cwd Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]
  live_stream true
  action :run
end
```

This compiles (and runs smoothly) on other machines (please disregard the [0m ):

```
[0m    execute("Install AD") do
[0m      action [:run]
[0m      default_guard_interpreter :execute
[0m      command "java -jar Installer-5.1.0.4-20190724.071744-2.exe -f c:/chef/cache/installer.xml"
[0m      backup 5
[0m      declared_type :execute
[0m      cookbook_name "run_me"
[0m      recipe_name "run_ad_installer"
[0m      cwd "c:/chef/cache"
[0m      live_stream true
[0m      domain nil
[0m      user nil
[0m    end
```

This fails with:

```
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '-1'
---- Begin output of java -jar Installer-5.1.0.4-20190724.071744-2.exe -f c:/chef/cache/ad_installer.xml ----
STDOUT: [ Automated installation FAILED! ]
STDERR: Command line arguments: -f c:/chef/cache/installer.xml
---- End output of java -jar Installer-5.1.0.4-20190724.071744-2.exe -f c:/chef/cache/installer.xml ----
```

Trying to figure out on my own, but it seems that debugging this is not my strong point :(

Maybe the below info helps:

```
    chef_version=15.0.300
[0m    platform=windows
[0m    platform_version=6.3.9600
[0m    ruby=ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x64-mingw32]
[0m    program_name=C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client
[0m    executable=C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What program are you intending to install?  `Install AD`, `run_ad_installer`, and `Installer-#s.exe` are too generic for me to guess.  AD on windows sounds like "Active Directory", but that doesn't seem to fit here.  It's worth noting that java -jar usually takes a file ending in `.jar`, not `.exe`.

Comment: Your `java -jar Installer.exe` does return `Automated installation FAILED!`, that all it gives back, so you'll have to check the logs of this installer or whatever as Chef can't give you more information. What is failing si your installer here.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this. It finally worked by giving the user, under which all the commands ran, a bit more permissions